Accessing Partner Center customers via API
First off, my question is equivalent to this post on the MS forums, but nobody has resolved it.
I am trying to get access to any API that allows me to view user counts for all our customers, Graph or Partner Center API.
My two basic requirements:

Read the full list of customers from Partner Center
Be able to use a single App credential to generate a Graph API access token for any Partner Center customer to access their user lists.

I've read the docs for the Partner Center API and I am following the REST authentication example, but the Partner Center API returns a 403 error no matter how I try to authenticate.
I am using OAuth 2.0 to authenticate with the https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token route with grant_type: client_credentials and resource: https://graph.windows.net, as stated in the documentation linked above.
This successfully returns a token, however when I use that as Bearer for the https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers route, I get a 403 Forbidden error.
I've also found this other token route that is not referenced in other documentation. When I try sending a POST to https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/generatetoken with this access token as bearer and grant_type: jwt_token, I get back {"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid authorization bearer is passed"}.

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53712/unable-to-retrieve-offers-from-partner-center-for?page=2#answers

@Rukmini Thank you, we've been looking for a "Developer settings" or "App management" in the Partner Center portal but have never been able to find it. Not even from the global admin account. The buttons are just not there where the documentation says they should be.

Microsoft removed the link to App Management in the sidebar but their direct shortcut link still works: https://aka.ms/accountexp/appMgmt This redirects for me to https://partner.microsoft.com/dashboard/v2/account-settings/appmanagement

Even I faced the same issue to reproduce in my environment. Try with the direct link and let me know

@Rukmini Sorry that took so long, I had to get an admin to test it for me just to be sure. The page no longer works. Clicking to add a web app or a native app does not do anything, it just loads for a second and stops.

Yeah can you make use of refresh token model to call the API? Is that feasible for you?

@Rukmini I don't think so, we need to call this server-side using App credentials. Is there a way to use a single App credential to generate Graph API access tokens for another tenant? I've tried using a client's tenant ID in the OAuth request and I get: The client application  is missing service principal in the tenant . That and being able to get a list of all customer tenants is what I'm looking for essentially.

Yes you can do it can you include what is the Microsoft Graph Api your are calling

@Rukmini Right now I just need to read the basic list of users for our client tenants, but once I get this working there will probably be more. Then I also need a way to list all customers to get their tenant IDs

Please edit the question regarding this requirement with the token generation details and the error and the APIs used

@Rukmini Added requirements. We are an MSP that manages many Azure tenants via Partner Center. I'm just the programmer not the Azure expert so I'm not 100% familiar with the terminology.

Sure Are you the member of the customer tenant?

@Rukmini I am a member of the top-level tenant, and the App is under the top-level tenant.

To achieve your requirement the customer tenant admin must accept the consent is that possible in your scenario?

And to list users in the customer tenant one should be the member of the customer tenant

@Rukmini We have GDAP consent already for all permissions with all of our tenants. We have all the customer tenant admin credentials. I just don't want to have to manage separate App creds for every tenant. I want to access all tenants with the same creds.

That's Great, I will post an answer step by step to fetch users of other tenants shortly

The error "The client application TenantID is missing service principal in the tenant CustomerTenantID" usually occurs if the Multitenant application is not present in the Customer Tenant as Service principal.
To access all tenants with the same application, check the below:
Assuming your tenant as TenantA and customer tenant as CustomerTenant
Created a multi-tenant application in TenantA by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)" and grant User.Read.All Microsoft Graph API permission:

Now to resolve the error, make use of below endpoint and login with the CustomerTenant Global Admin account, so that it creates Service Principal in  CustomerTenant*:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/CustomerTenantTenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientIDOFAPPinTenantA 

OR

https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientIDOFAPPinTenantA 


Once, you click on Accept and go to CustomerTenant -> Enterprise applications -> Search the application:
The service principal is created in the CustomerTenant and the API permissions is granted:

Now generate the access token for Microsoft Graph API to access users of CustomerTenant
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

I logged in with the CustomerTenant  account and able to get the user details for the CustomerTenant successfully:

Now to test, I logged with TenantA  account and got the users of TenantA :


You can also directly generate the access token using CustomerTenant global admin account and you will get the consent screen to accept the permissions instead of creating the service principal by the endpoint.
You can make use of refresh token model to access customers in Microsoft Partner Center. Refer this SO Thread by me.

References:
azure - Search User Information Across different Microsoft Tenants - Stack Overflow by Tiny Wang
azure - Is it possible to create a User (Microsoft Entra ID) for Tenant B from Tenant A? - Stack Overflow by me

That worked! Thank you. However now the second part of my question was how to get a list of all our tenants? I need a way to get the tenant IDs to authenticate with. I've found out we do not have access to the Partner Center API because we are an indirect bill partner.

Please post a new question with all details I will help you there and paste the question link here

Done, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78902051/get-a-list-of-customer-tenants-without-partner-center-api-access

Sure will check
