Get a list of customer tenants without Partner Center API access
I need to find out how to get a list of our Partner Center customer tenants without access to the Partner Center API as we do not meet the criteria to access it.
We have GDAP relationships with every tenant, as well as an App Registration that has consent with every tenant. Is there a way in the Graph API to access a list of tenants associated with our account? I really only need the Tenant IDs and nothing else.

Do you want to get the TenantId of other tenant?

@Rukmini I need to get a list of customer tenant IDs. We need to access the Graph API for all of our tenants but first the app needs to be able to find the tenant IDs in the first place as it does not have any knowledge of them, or what tenants exist at all.

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78382478/how-to-authenticate-to-microsoft-partner-center-using-azure-automation#78384507

@Rukmini As I said, we do not have access to the Partner Center API because we do not meet Microsoft's criteria for it. We confirmed this by asking MS support already.

AFAIK then it's not possible to get the tenants IDs

@Rukmini Alright thank you. We do have a dirtier alternative way to source these so that will have to do.

Can you please elaborate the alternative?

@Rukmini It has nothing to do with MS APIs. I'm being told by our admin that they have a way they can import all the Tenant IDs into ITGlue, which we use for organizing client information/docs/passwords etc. I can then use that API to get them.

Okay can I post as a answer that it's not possible?

@Rukmini Sure, one more question though. Is there maybe a way to view the tenants that are consented with the app? Shouldn't the Graph API have a way to see that?

I will check that and post as an answer?

@Rukmini Yes, thank you

If you have a list of customer domains, you can get the corresponding tenant id. This can be done with a simple non-authenticated request, which can easily be seen in the network tab of the page https://www.whatismytenantid.com

Note that: It is not possible to get a list of our Partner Center customer tenants without access to the Partner Center API as we do not meet the criteria to access it.
Hence, you must be having access to the Partner Center API. In case if you get access check the below:
Connect to Partner Center, use the below script:
$appId = "ClientID"
$appSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Secret" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenantId = "TenantID" 
$credential = [PSCredential]::new($appId, $appSecret)

$tokenSplat = @{
    ApplicationId        = $appId
    Credential           = $credential
    Scopes               = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation"
    ServicePrincipal     = $true
    TenantId             = $tenantId
    UseAuthorizationCode = $true
}

$token = New-PartnerAccessToken @tokenSplat

$token.RefreshToken


Now connect to Partner Center:
$connectSplat = @{
    ApplicationId = $appId
    Credential    = $credential
    RefreshToken  = $token.RefreshToken
}

Connect-PartnerCenter @connectSplat

As confirmed by you as you have the access there is no way to get access to Partner Center API.

Is there maybe a way to view the tenants that are consented with the app? Shouldn't the Graph API have a way to see that?

To fetch the tenants the multitenant application has consented, you need to be the user of that particular tenant.

Hence, there is no way to view the tenants that are consented with the app via Microsoft Graph API or any other API.

Reference:
Azure AD Multi-tenant App - Find what tenant provided admin consent - Stack Overflow by RamaraoAdapa
